# Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY with Multiple INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with multiple content types and users, as well as a separate database with likes. I'm trying to figure out which users have received the most likes for *any* of their content, no matter what the type.

I've been able to figure out queries for finding the most liked users by specific content types, but going with *any* content type is proving to be a bit more difficult.

It might be worth noting that there are millions of records in this database.

Here's the work I've been doing on creating a query... I'm pretty sure it's not correct!

```
SELECT picture.user_id, video.creator_id, post.author_id
FROM likes_service.likes
INNER JOIN prod.pictures picture ON likes.obj_id = picture.id
INNER JOIN prod.videos video ON likes.obj_id = video.id
INNER JOIN prod.posts post ON likes.obj_id = post.id
GROUP BY picture.user_id, video.creator_id, post.author_id
ORDER BY COUNT(picture.user_id), COUNT(video.creator_id), COUNT(post.author_id) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Could anybody please give me a hint or point me in the right direction? I feel like I'm getting close...

Thanks!

Comment: why do you name the three different vars with the same label?

Comment: You should not be selecting columns which are not in your aggregate.

Comment: @Rubens Figured maybe that'd help somehow? I guess not!

Comment: @EricR MySQL generously extends the `GROUP BY` functionality to allow you to `SELECT` columns which are not in `GROUP BY`. This is bad practice as other DBMS's do not allow this.

Comment: @njk: *‘This is bad practice as other DBMS's do not allow this’* – I might agree with the former, but the latter is not entirely correct. SQLite also supports "hidden GROUP BY columns". If I'm not much mistaken, there's a limited support for that in PostgreSQL too (only when you a grouping by a primary key column, I think).

Comment: @AndriyM I stand corrected. * Most

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a UNION, not a multi-way JOIN.

```
select objects.user_id user_id, sum(likes.like_count) like_count
from (
    select user_id, id
    from prod.pictures
    union all
    select creator_id, id
    from prod.videos
    union all
    select author_id, id
    from prod.posts) objects
join (select obj_id, count(*) likes_count
      from likes_service.likes
      group by obj_id) likes on likes.obj_id = objects.id
group by user_id
order by like_count desc
```

Comment: This points out a possible problem with your database design. It would be better if there were a single table for all type-agnostic information about documents (e.g. the author), with references to the type-specific tables.

Comment: When I try to run it using your example, I get: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous. It may be worth to note that I have a user_id field in the likes table as well.

Comment: Is there a `user_id` column in the `likes` table? I've added a qualifier to avoid ambiguity. Although I fail to see why you couldn't figure this out yourself.

Comment: I did figure it out. Right after I posted that I realized what was going on :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. I have 20 million + likes in the database, and the query is going to take forever. I'm worried it'll kill the server.

Comment: @Eric: with large pictures, videos and posts table, this query will spin quite materializing that inline view (generating the intermediate MyISAM derived table). You'll likely get better performance getting the count of likes first, filtering that down to a reasonable number (i see LIMIT 20 in your query), and then joining that to the individual tables.

Comment: I've made a small change that I think should improve the join efficiency, by grouping the `likes` table first.

Comment: Will this query load the entirety of the posts, videos, and pictures tables? There are millions of records in each, and I'm worried it'll crash our database server.

Comment: No, it just loads the `user_id` and `id` columns of those tables, not all the content data. And if these columns are indexed, loading them should be optimized.

Comment: If many of the items in the posts, videos, and pictures tables have no likes, you might be able to improve things by joining each with likes __before__ doing the union. Or you could use spencer7593's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are wanting the users that has an object with the most likes listed, or whether you are looking for the users that have the most overall likes spread over all their content.

Consider a user who has just one photo which has 1,000 likes, should that user get listed before a user with a total of 100 photos, videos and posts with an average like count of 20, with the highest number of likes at 50?

Those are two different queries.

For now, I'm going to assume that what you want to find is the "most liked" items, and then find which users each of those objects was created/authored by. To find the 20 "most liked" items, it's pretty straightforward to find which "`obj_id`"s have the most likes...

```
SELECT l.obj_id
     , COUNT(1) AS like_count
  FROM likes_service.likes l
 GROUP BY l.obj_id
ORDER BY like_count DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

I'm assuming (based on your original query), and absent a schema and sample data, that the values of `obj_id` in the `likes` table reference an `id` value of a single object in one of the other tables... that is, an `obj_id` value won't appear in both the `photos` and `videos` table. (Otherwise, you'd probably have a column somewhere next to `obj_id` to tell you which table the `obj_id` was referencing.)

We use that previous query as an inline view (MySQL calls it a derived table), and give it a convenient alias of "ml" (most liked), and we'll do a LEFT JOIN to each of the target object tables (photos, videos, posts), to figure out what kind of item it is, and who the user/creator/author is.

```
SELECT ml.obj_id
     , ml.like_count
     , p.user_id
     , v.creator_id
     , t.author_id
  FROM ( SELECT l.obj_id
              , COUNT(1) AS like_count
           FROM likes_service.likes l
          GROUP BY l.obj_id
          ORDER BY like_count DESC
          LIMIT 0,20
       ) ml
  LEFT
  JOIN prod.pictures p
    ON p.id = ml.obj_id
  LEFT
  JOIN prod.videos v
    ON v.id = ml.obj_id
  LEFT
  JOIN prod.videos v
    ON v.id = ml.obj_id
  LEFT
  JOIN prod.posts t
    ON t.id = ml.obj_id
 ORDER BY ml.like_count DESC
```

Assuming that the `user_id` column from the photos table is NOT NULL, and the `creator_id from the`videos` table is NOT NULL ...

Then you can determine which table the obj_id was found in.  i.e. if the `user_id` column is not null, you know it's from the photos table, if the `creator_id` is not null, you know its from the videos table.

You could add some expressions in that outermost select to decipher that...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.user_id    IS NOT NULL THEN 'photo'
            WHEN v.creator_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'video'
            WHEN t.author_ID  IS NOT NULL THEN 'post'
       END AS obj_type
     , CASE WHEN p.user_id    IS NOT NULL THEN p.user_id
            WHEN v.creator_id IS NOT NULL THEN v.creator_id
            WHEN t.author_id  IS NOT NULL THEN t.author_id
       END AS user_id
     , l.obj_id
```